# Visual Basic time synchronizing

Tags: vb.net, time, synchronization

I am working oin a project in vb.net although I am not an expert in it, I just used it because U think it is the best for this kind of problem.

I have a project with two buttons and a label; first button is for sync windows date from a server and the other is to change the windows date to (2014, 11, 16). I am doing this because some programs I have doesn't run unless the date is this one and as you know browser must be the real time to run this is the idea of this project.

The second button is working perfectly, but the sync date button doesn't work and throws this error in my label

> No connection because the target machine refused to connect

Here is my function and my server ip

```
 Public Function GetNISTTime(ByVal host As String) As String

    Dim timeStr As String = ""

    Try
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(New TcpClient(host, 13).GetStream)
        LastSysTime = DateTime.UtcNow()
        timeStr = reader.ReadToEnd()
        reader.Close()
    Catch ex As SocketException
        GetNISTTime = ex.Message
        Exit Function
    Catch ex As Exception
        GetNISTTime = ex.Message
        Exit Function
    End Try

    'Dim jd As Integer = Integer.Parse(timeStr.Substring(1, 5))
    'Dim yr As Integer = Integer.Parse(timeStr.Substring(7, 2))
    'Dim mo As Integer = Integer.Parse(timeStr.Substring(10, 2))
    'Dim dy As Integer = Integer.Parse(timeStr.Substring(13, 2))
    'Dim hr As Integer = Integer.Parse(timeStr.Substring(16, 2))
    'Dim mm As Integer = Integer.Parse(timeStr.Substring(19, 2))
    'Dim sc As Integer = Integer.Parse(timeStr.Substring(22, 2))
    'Dim Temp As Integer = CInt(AscW(timeStr(7)))

    Return timeStr ' New DateTime(yr + 2000, mo, dy, hr, mm, sc)

End Function
```

and the button

```
Private Sub real_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles real.Click
    GetNISTTime("mail.harf.com.sa")
    Label1.Text = GetNISTTime("mail.harf.com.sa").ToString
End Sub
```

I think the problem is because of the server but I didn't find any dns server that does sync successfully.

This is my program download link if you want to see the problem in with your eyes (you should run it as adminstrator)

http://www.mediafire.com/file/wfw5jpag8w2hofb/Release.rar/file

Also it must be dns in Saudi Arabia time zone

Comment: If you want to sync the clock it's better to just run the command `net start w32time & w32tm /resync /force` through CMD. You can Invoke it using [`Process.Start()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_System_String_) with `cmd` as the executable and `/C net start w32time & w32tm /resync /force` as the args.

Comment: thank you very much worked perfectly ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i did like what Visual Vincent say and this is my code after editing it 
and it worked perfectly with me just need administrator permissions
code

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Daytime

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim d As DateTime
        d = "12:52:00"

        Try
            Microsoft.VisualBasic.TimeOfDay = d 'Your time...
            Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateString = New Date(2014, 11, 16) 'The date...
        Catch ex As Exception
            'You might have to run as Administrator...?
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub real_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles real.Click
        Process.Start("CMD", "/C net start w32time & w32tm /resync /force & pause")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function call is not correct.

```
Private Sub real_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles real.Click
    GetNISTTime("mail.harf.com.sa")
    Label1.Text = GetNISTTime("mail.harf.com.sa").ToString
End Sub
```

should be:

```
Private Sub real_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles real.Click
    Label1.Text = GetNISTTime("mail.harf.com.sa")
End Sub
```

`GetNISTTime` is a function that returns a string, so your original first line (`GetNISTTime("mail.harf.com.sa")`) does the work but nothing is done with the return value. Your original second line takes a return value that is a string and then tries to convert it to a string.

In addition, your function may not return anything if an error occurs. You have used a VBA style assignment in the `catch block`. Instead, try:

```
Public Function GetNISTTime(ByVal host As String) As String

    Dim timeStr As String = ""

    Try
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(New TcpClient(host, 13).GetStream)
        LastSysTime = DateTime.UtcNow()
        timeStr = reader.ReadToEnd()
        reader.Close()
    Catch ex As SocketException
        return ex.Message
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ex.Message
    End Try

    'any other stuff
    Return timeStr     
End Function
```

Comment: thanks bro for explaining the problem but i used the easiest way which is running sync by cmd from the previous comment thank you again i will publish my code for anyone who wants to use it